# Select 1 row and display it in a table with 2 columns

Tags: php, mysql

How can I make a `select` in database and display that row in a table  with 2 columns.
Here is my select

```
$query="select Interval from Interval_Orar";
$result=mysqli_query($dbc,$query) or die("query failed: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
echo '<table>';
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo'
        <tr>
        <td>'.$row['Interval'].'</td>
        </tr>';

}
echo '</table>';
```

what i what to display is a table like this

```
<tr>
<td>Interval 1</td>
<td>Interval 2</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Interval 3</td>
<td>Interval 4</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Interval 5</td>
<td>Interval 6</td>
</tr>
```

what i dont know to make is to put that 2 by 2 select in the while

Comment: on the second colum i still want to have $row['Interval']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just do another `mysqli_fetch_array`  in the loop, check if there was a result 
and display either an empty cell or one with the content.
Then at the end of the loop you only need to check if the second `mysqli_fetch_array` had a result. (The empty cell is optional, it depends if you require it e.g. for styling, add `not value` or other things)

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo'<tr>';

  echo '<td>'.$row['Interval'].'</td>';

  $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  if( $row ) {
    echo '<td>'.$row['Interval'].'</td>';
  } else {
    echo '<td></td>';
  }

  echo '</tr>';
  if( !$row ) {
    break;
  }

}
```

Another way would be to use a `$counter` and a `$counter%2` to check in which column the result should be displayed and if an `<tr>` or `</tr>` needs to be added, but that would require more work.

**EDIT**
This is not tested as I neither have `php` not a `mysql` setup server right here, but making a function out of it would allow you to re use it with any column count:

```
function createRows( $result, $columns ) {
    if( $columns <= 0 ) {
      return;
    }
    $row = true; //initialize it with true so that the first mysqli_fetch_array will be called
    while($row !== null ) {
      echo'<tr>';

      for( $i=0 ; $i<columns ; $i++ ) {
        if( $row !== null && $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
          echo '<td>'.$row['Interval'].'</td>';
        } else {
          echo '<td></td>';
        }
      }
      echo '</tr>';

    }
}
```

Comment: Thnx alot, first method worked perfect. If i want to put on 3 collums i just need to make another mysqli_fetch_array? i'll accept your answer in 3 mins :)

Comment: Yes you could do that. But you should check if it is valid to call `mysqli_fetch_array` another time after the previous call returned `null` (As I don't know it right now for sure I added the `if( !$row ) { break; }` which is probably optional)

Comment: @user3058067 update my answer but as i mentioned there you need to take care as I can't test it right now.

Answer (score 0):

Dump your entire result set into an array so you can manually move the pointer.
The inside your loop it would be (in plain English)

column1 = row1
column2 = row1+1

row = row + 1

repeat.